# Building a django queryset over foreign key and onetoone

Tags: python, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have some two models (in different apps/models.py files) related with User:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False)
    ...


class CourseStudent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester)
    ...
```

I am trying to get a queryset of all profiles that have at least one course in the current semester.

How can I generate a queryset of profiles, where `profile.user` has at least one `CourseStudent` instance, and filtered so that `coursestudent.semester=current_semester`?

Since a student may have multiple courses in the semester, the duplicates also need to be removed (unique profiles only in the queryset)

EDIT:  I am using postgresql and trying to figure out if I need to use [distinct with an argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. Maybe you should try

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False)
    ...


class CourseStudent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="course_student")
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester)

Profile.objects.filter("what_you_want").exclude(user__courser_student=None).distinct()
```